# Check if you can use unwind segue before using a push segue

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

In a navigation using segues, from the root controller we can push controller A or B.

From A we can push C which can push B which later can unwind to A to restart the process.

From B we can push A which can push C which later can unwind to B to restart the process.

In B we have button which says "Go to A" which has to unwind or push the controller A depending on the scenario.

[image: diagram]

**How can I know easily if I can unwind before preforming the push segue?**

For now I use the navigationController array to check if the previous controller is C to push or unwind. I would like to know a generic solution for this kind of cycles using segues, for example:

if *B can unwind to A* **then** unwind **else** push A

So, the question is, how can I check *B can unwind to A* without accessing the navigationController array?

Comment: Sadly no, I had to implement a workaround to set a 'unwindMode' in B, then when it wants to present A it checks the mode to use the push segue or the unwind segue

Comment: Why don't you simply use popToRootViewController since your purpose here is to navigate back to root view controller as far as i understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my generic solution to this problem, for a Swift app:

- assume UINavigationController containment
- define `unwindToXXX:` methods in each XXX you want to unwind to
- in each YYY that could either unwind or push to XXX, define segues `unwindToXXX` and `showXXX`

Then you can simply call `gotoController("unWindToXXX", "showXXX")` given

```
func gotoController(unwind: String, show: String) {
    let action = Selector(unwind + ":")
    if let target = navigationController?.viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction(action, fromViewController: self, withSender: self)
    {
        assert(target.canPerformUnwindSegueAction(action, fromViewController: self, withSender: self))
        performSegueWithIdentifier(unwind, sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier(show, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction is deprecated in iOS 9.0.